# Swift - How To Make A Table Containing Labels

Tags: ios, swift

This is what I want to achieve.

[image]

I tried coding it myself but the first outer view border does not show up.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class InfoTableView: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        let outerBorder = UIColorCode.init(hexString: "#666666")
    let startingTopPoint   = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY)
    let endingTopPoint  = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY)

    let startingPoint   = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY)
    let endingPoint     = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY)

        // top
        let tpPath = UIBezierPath()
        tpPath.moveToPoint(startingPoint)
        tpPath.addLineToPoint(endingTopPoint)
        tpPath.lineWidth = 2.0

        outerBorder.setStroke()
        tpPath.stroke()

        // bottom
        let btPath = UIBezierPath()

        btPath.moveToPoint(startingPoint)
        btPath.addLineToPoint(endingPoint)
        btPath.lineWidth = 2.0

        outerBorder.setStroke()
        btPath.stroke()

    }
}
```

There are outer borders top and bottom. But only the bottom one shows up. I don't know where did I go wrong.

Comment: hi John, try look on UITableView, it is customizable and easier to have dynamic data

Comment: @john Instead of reinventing the wheel, I thing you should give a try to UITableView and try to customise UITableViewCell. You can get your output by little customisation and less coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made little bit of edits on your code . Try if it works for you.

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let outerBorder = UIColor.redColor()
        let lineWidth : CGFloat = 2.0
        let insetRect = rect.insetBy(dx: lineWidth/2, dy: lineWidth/2)
        let startingTopPoint   = CGPointMake(insetRect.origin.x,insetRect.origin.y)
        let endingTopPoint  = CGPoint(x: insetRect.maxX, y: insetRect.minY)

        let startingPoint   = CGPoint(x: insetRect.minX, y: insetRect.maxY)
        let endingPoint     = CGPoint(x: insetRect.maxX, y: insetRect.maxY)

        // top
        let tpPath = UIBezierPath()
        tpPath.moveToPoint(startingTopPoint)
        tpPath.addLineToPoint(endingTopPoint)
        tpPath.lineWidth = 2.0

        outerBorder.setStroke()
        tpPath.stroke()

        // bottom
        let btPath = UIBezierPath()

        btPath.moveToPoint(startingPoint)
        btPath.addLineToPoint(endingPoint)
        btPath.lineWidth = 2.0

        outerBorder.setStroke()
        btPath.stroke()
    }
```